# Android Studio - warn: removing resource not found

Tags: android-studio

All of a sudden I'm receiving Android Studio errors when I try to build my app. It happend today in the morning when I started up my laptop, while yesterday it didn't. Android Studio says that I'm missing a `string resource` and 2 `drawables` which are nowhere to be found in my project nor used.

The error:

```
Output:  warn: removing resource nl.coffeeit.inlite:string/status_bar_notification_info_overflow without required default value.
C:\Users\Maffia\AndroidStudioProjects\In-Lite\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v21\values-v21.xml:301: error: resource drawable/notification_action_background (aka nl.coffeeit.inlite:drawable/notification_action_background) not found.
C:\Users\Maffia\AndroidStudioProjects\In-Lite\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v21\values-v21.xml:306: error: resource dimen/notification_action_text_size (aka nl.coffeeit.inlite:dimen/notification_action_text_size) not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Maffia\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\6c2b371e8419c4016ded3efc6f9ea641\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Maffia\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Maffia\AndroidStudioProjects\In-Lite\android\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\resources\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Maffia\AndroidStudioProjects\In-Lite\android\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Maffia\AndroidStudioProjects\In-Lite\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Maffia\AndroidStudioProjects\In-Lite\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        nl.coffeeit.inlite\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        440dpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Maffia\AndroidStudioProjects\In-Lite\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

I have no idea where those `resources` come from. I've tried multiple things to solve this issue:

- clean project
- rebuild project
- clear build directory
- invalidate caches/restart
- reviewed all my layout and string resources for errors
- restart my laptop
- even tried to revert to previous git commits, didn't work
- tried adding the specified string resource, still the two drawables
  popup as error
- re-created git project twice

Does anyone know what could be wrong? I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by doing the following:

1. copy the Android Studio project to a different location
2. remove `C:/Users/username/.gradle/caches`
3. re-open the copied project in step 1

Everything is working again. Although I still don't understand what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it just by moving the project to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember any last Library you introduced in your app or try to remember some last code edits you did, it would help to resolve this issue.

If it doesn't work delete this folder.

```
 C:\Users\Maffia\.androidstudio
```

This folder contains caches only and its name is appended along with android studio version.

Comment: I didn't edit anything. I even tried to go back to previous commits. It still didn't work.

As for your suggestion, I kind of did this when I updated Android Studio to the latest version. I refused to import my old settings. But just did it again and didn't work.